# My app runs too fast on some Android devices

Tags: android

I just released an app, Avoid The Spikes! on the android market.
Some friends of mine have downloaded the apps on their phones/tablets, and I am told it runs too fast. It runs just fine on my android (HTC Dream). Is there any way to tell how much faster it would run on certain androids, and how to adjust it accordingly? I have searched low and high and have yet to find an answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: define *runs too fast* in better detail. Is the frame rate incorrect? Does a timer end earlier than it should? Do algorithms take less time than they should? What exactly runs too fast?

Answer (score 5):

I have seen your game on Android Market and tried it.

You cannot actually determine the minimal and maximal speed you will obtain on the various existing hardware, as:

- New hardware appear on the market every day
- On a given hardware, other factors may influence the execution speed of your app.

What you should do is making your game independant of the framerate. To do so, avoid making your objects moving of a fixed distance each time you update their position. Prefer making them moving of a fixed distance **for a certain amount of time**.

To do so, measure the time elapsed since the last update each time you are updating the object's position, and calculate the distance to move to accordingly.

This way, depending of the quality of the hardware, these objects will jump or move nicely, but at least they will do so at the same speed, and this speed will be determined by you. This is a bit the same thing when you are playing a FPS game on a brand new machine or an old one: the speed of the motion is constant, only the framerate is not. On the old machine you have the impression the objects jump, while on the new they move gracefully, but it works in both cases (well, whithin certain limits, of course, for the old machine). And a machine can NEVER be too fast that way.

To give you some pseudo-code, for a paratrooper falling from the top to the bottom of the screen:

- this is the loop to avoid:

  ```
  while (playing) { 
      update_positions();
      display();   
  }

  update_positions() {
      paratrooper.y -= 10; // the paratrooper's altitude decreases of 10 at each update
  }
  ```

On a slow hardware it will take hours to cross the screen. On a fast hardware this will be way too fast, you won't even see the paratrooper falling.

- this is the proper way to do:

  ```
  while (playing) { 
      update_positions();
      display();   
  }

  update_positions() {
      time_elapsed = getSystemTimeInMS() - lastUpdateTimeInMS();
      paratrooper.y -= 0.01 * time_elapsed; // the paratrooper's altitude decreases of 10 per second

      setLastUpdateTimeMS(getSystemTimeInMS()); // This way it includes the calculation time
  }
  ```

On a slow hardware, crossing the whole screen may take 15 displays while on fast hardware it would take 45 displays, but in every cases your paratrooper is falling at 10dp per second.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your app is a game? If so, you probably have a game loop that just runs the game as fast as possible. I've found this post about implementing game loops to be very useful: [Game Loops](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/), when I created my game which involved time.